# passing parameters from java to c# app goes wrong

Tags: c#, java, command-line, parameters, arguments

Hi I have a very annoying problem and I can't understand the reasons.

I have a c# form application which receives some args in main and uses them to connect to a device (ip,port,user,passw).
It also prints these arguments to see if they are correct.

Now if I call the exe with arguments from windows prompt all goes right.
But if I do the same thing from java using the Runtime exec() function the application starts,prints the correct arguments exactly in the same way as before BUT DOES NOT CONNECT!!

it's like arguments were wrong....any suggestion?? maybe exec passing is not the same as prompt??

I have debugged the process with vs and the variable are identical in both case but the connect function (which reminds to a third part library from device vendor)

code

```
public MyForm(string[] args) 
{ 
   InitializeComponent(); 
   if (args.Length > 0) 
   { 
      this.IP = args[0]; 
      this.PASSWORD = args[4]; 
      this.ID = args[3]; 
      this.PORT = args[1]; 
      this.logTextArea.AppendText("Connection to " +
                    IP +":"+PORTA+" "+ID+" "+
                    PASSWORD+"\n"); 
   } else set fixed values


JAVA
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("MyForm.exe IP PORT NOT_USED ID PASSW");
```

Comment: Could it be that the C# application needs elevated privileges?

Comment: Why don't you use web service to transfer data between two apps?

Comment: i dont know...anyway calling from java is different in privileges terms?I tought that exec() is only a way to call exes...after that exe should do his work like calling from prompt...or not??  @Vijay because is the java company app that simply have to run C++/C# apps...one for each device brand...is not useful to build up a web service only for few parameters i think

Comment: I think what Cthulhu means is that you may need to run as Administrator.  Could it be you are running cmd as Admin but not your java application?  If you always need your app to run as admin, you can add a manifest file to your project and set requestedExecutionLevel="requireAdministrator".

Comment: java app is run from eclipse....i tried to build a jar and exec from cmd but same result....

Comment: update: tried on different pc with admin privileges same result :(

Comment: Maybe in eclipse your java app can't find MyForm.exe.  Try put your exe at the project root folder if not already done so.  By the way, what error you're getting?

Comment: i find the exe very well and it's start and print parameters correctly but seems that it cannot use the library to connect